# ASP.NET Insert Only Details View with Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, webforms

I am using ASP.NET webforms and Entity Framework. I'm trying to have just a simple insert form using a Details View. I do not want to edit, delete, or select entries from this Details View, only Insert new entries.

In the insert, I want to insert new people.
The structure of a person is: Name, Manager, Location

I have two Entity Data Sources, one that represents Managers and one that represents Locations
I have two DropDownLists in the InsertItemTemplate that can select manager and location.

My problem is that when I place the DetailsView (DefaultMode = insert) and add the data source for the people entity, the DetailsView shows an entry from the database as well as the drop down lists and name fields. I might be missing something simple but I can't seem to get a DetailsView for insert only that has DropDownLists populated by other Entity Data Sources.

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
        DefaultMode="Insert" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList DataSourceID = "ManagerEntitySource" runat="server" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList DataSourceID = "LocationEntitySource" runat="server" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="AddEmployeeDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=SafetyEntities" DefaultContainerName="SafetyEntities" 
        EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EntitySetName="Employees">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: Could you show the code for this `DetailsView`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant to put it in and forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but if you only want insert mode, try removing the AutoGenerateInsertButton property, and add a CommandField with ShowInsertButton = True in the Fields property.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
    DefaultMode="Insert">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField = "Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList DataSourceID = "ManagerEntitySource" runat="server" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList DataSourceID = "LocationEntitySource" runat="server" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```